# I am trying to deploy a project on github pages '[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "framer-motion" from "/src/components/Services.jsx".'

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, tailwind-css, github-pages, vite

I am trying to build a React, Tailwind, Vite project on github pages. I have deployed projects before and not ran into any issues but I am getting this issue on build -
  `Rollup failed to resolve import "framer-motion" from "/home/runner/work/Refine/Refine/src/components/ Services ".`

I have been trying to debug for a few hours now.

The repo link is https://github.com/JaredFunaro/Refine

I believe you can view the action reports to get a better idea of what is going on, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: I tried to include more code in this but even if i formatted it as code stackoverflow kept yelling at me so sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are importing `framer-motion` but is not listed as a dependency.

Simple install it by running:

```
npm install framer-motion
```

Comment: Hm, Yes it wasn't listed under Dependencies in package.json but it was still working and utilizing that library locally when running a dev server, I went ahead and did what you said, and I also updated my vite config back to the basics without the rollout options, but I still got the error after deployment of it being unable to find index.css - "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: Not finding `index.css` is a differente problem, I'm glad that you could fix it. But the original question was related to `framer-motion` and it probably was because of it not being listed as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't able to find the css and other files because I forgot to add the 'base' option in vite config for deployment!

my original vite.config.js file was -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

I just had to update the base option to reflect the name of github repo, so the github repo was named "Refine"
so I updated the vite.config.js file to say -

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/Refine/"
})
```